# Looking for a list of performance counters that require a machine name

Tags: c#, devexpress, performancecounter

Ultimately, I'm trying to use a performance counter to monitor how many active SQL connections I have running during an import.  But at the moment, I'm just wondering if anyone has a list of performance counters categories that require a machine name.

Comment: Have you done any research?

Comment: Yep.  Most of the morning and several hours yesterday.  Can't find a list.  Presently going through categories that have counters and instances and machine names.  Laborious.